# java.lang.runtimeExeception unable to start activity componentInfo

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to create an android app that gets poll data from the realclearpolitics website and converts it into a graph. It is supposed to store each of the columns in the poll table on the website into an arraylist using jsoup. When I run the app, however, i'm getting an exception.

```
package com.pollapp.presidentialelectionpolls;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Document doc;
Element table;
Elements rows;
ListView dispData;
ArrayList<String> nameOfSrc = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> dateWidth = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Trump = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Clinton = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dispData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        doc = Jsoup
                .connect(
                        "http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/us/general_election_trump_vs_clinton-5491.html")
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    table = doc.select("table").get(1);
    rows = table.select("tr");

    for (int i = 2; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
        Element row = rows.get(i);
        Elements cols = row.select("td");
        nameOfSrc.add(cols.get(0).text());
        dateWidth.add(cols.get(1).text());
        Trump.add(cols.get(4).text());
        Clinton.add(cols.get(5).text());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Trump);
    dispData.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

here is my logcat info:

```
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pollapp.presidentialelectionpolls/com.pollapp.presidentialelectionpolls.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.pollapp.presidentialelectionpolls.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-10 06:42:13.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Look at your stack trace. What is there on `MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong table (there are four an the side, not two as assumed) resulting in only two entries in `rows`.

Try:

```
table = doc.select("table.data.large").get(1);
```

I would also recommend to verify `doc` is valid after the try-catch block and react accordingly or move the following code using the Document also into the try-catch block, otherwise the chance of running into unhandled exceptions is very high (for example if the server is not reachable, etc.).

Comment: there are two tables on the website, and I want to retrieve 4 out of the six columns in the second table, which is what the four arraylists are for. Does ".first()" get the first or second table?

Comment: There are four tables on the page, hence your problem. If your want the detailed one on the lower page chose `.get(1)`again (changing my answer accordingly), so `nameOfSrc` would contain from BloombergBloomberg to QuinnipiacQuinnipiac.

Comment: I want the big table with all the polls on the bottom

Comment: Yes and thats the one you getting with doc.select("table.data.large").get(1);`

Comment: but isn't the table's html tag <table> rather than <table.data.large>?

Comment: I'm using the css classes as selectors to filter out the other two tables, that we don't want to use. That leaves the two tables with the polling data and from those two we chose the second one one the lower page (get(1) instead get(0)).

Comment: `table = doc.select("table").get(3);` should also work, since it is the fourth table on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Variable doc equals null. This maybe because:

- No internet connection
- Wrong url

**Try this**

```
try{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    Boolean isConnect = ni == null ? false : ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if(isConnect){
        doc = Jsoup
                    .connect("http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/us/general_election_trump_vs_clinton-5491.html")
                    .get();
    }
} catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I checked, and both my URL is right and my internet is working. are there any other reasons for this?